# Reducedness and the choice of affine open subsets

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be a scheme and $p\in X$. Let $U, V$ be two affine open subschemes containing $p$. I wonder if $p$ is reduced as a prime ideal (ring) in the affine scheme $U$, is it necessarily reduced as a prime ideal (ring) in the affine scheme $V$?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "**$p$  is reduced as a prime ideal (ring)** in the affine scheme U?"?

Comment: @user347489 Well, the affine scheme U is Spec(A) for some ring A and P in U is a prime ideal of A. P is reduced as a ring.

Comment: @TiWen but a prime ideal is not a ring..

Comment: @symmetric_cow it's a ring without unit.

Comment: I don't know what your interest in this is, but you got me to look into what can be said about the geometry of non-unital rings in the spirit of AG. Some of the answers in this MO thread are very interesting, IMO specially those of Emerton and JBorger: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34332/consequences-of-not-requiring-ring-homomorphisms-to-be-unital

Comment: @user347489 Thank you so much! My question may look weird when there is already a definition of reduced points using stalks. I asked it simply out of curiosity.